# How to get info button to appear and make it functional in jquery mobile or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

attached you will see a photo of an app that is a unit converter. In the picture it has small info buttons that are clickable and when clicked, information correlating to the input section nexts to it shows as an alert in the app and relays information about that section. I am wondering how this is accomplished and if it can be done using jQuery mobile and or JavaScript. [image: example photo I am referring to]

Comment: vote to close because You aren't actually showing research effort

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Your question is tagged jQuery Mobile, here is a possible solution using JQM. Please note, You don't even need the "OK" button. The JQM popup will close simply by tapping outside or by pressing the "Esc" key.

```css
.ui-info.ui-controlgroup-horizontal .ui-controlgroup-controls {
  display: block;
}
.ui-info.ui-controlgroup-horizontal .ui-controlgroup-controls .ui-input-text {
  margin-top: 0;
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}

.ui-info .ui-icon-info {
 float: right;
 padding: 0;
 height: 22px;
}

.ui-info .ui-icon-info:after {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  margin-top: -22px;
}

.ui-popup {
  max-width: 420px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div data-role="page">
    <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
      <h2>Header</h2></div>
    <div role="main" class="ui-content">
      <div data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" class="ui-info">
        <legend>Legend<a href="#info" data-rel="popup" data-transition="pop" class="ui-icon-info ui-btn-icon-notext" title="Info">Info</a></legend>
        <input name="text-basic" id="text-basic" value="" type="text">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
      <h2>Footer</h2></div>
    <div data-role="popup" data-position-to="window" id="info">
      <div data-role="header" data-theme="a">
        <h1>Title</h1>
      </div>
      <div role="main" class="ui-content">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery

```
$("#id_of_button").click(function(){
 alert("Named after the " + input_value1.value + " who invented " + input_value2.value + " etc..."); // Insert the values from your form inputs into this alert function
  });
```

Comment: Is there any css or jqmobile styling involved? Thank you for the jQuery code btw.

Comment: To just have a basic alert box show up after an "onclick" event, you don't need to add any extra CSS.

Comment: Should have specified. In order to get the little info icon that needs to be clicked, do I need css for that?

Comment: It depends but the short answer is no, you don't need CSS.  You can include the Bootstrap Library and use one of their glyphicons within a <span> tag like this: <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign></span>